How does Richard Stengel propose to do away with paywalls for news, "—at least during the 2024 election"?
In the Ideas section of The Atlantic, Richard Stengel's April 14, 2024 Democracy Dies Behind Paywalls; The case for making journalism free—at least during the 2024 election itself trails off into the same paywall it discusses.
To me, the press is an integral component of democracy (good journalism informs, and simutaneously helps counter fake news for example), and at the same time capitalism is pretty important as well. Journalists and their support and distribution must be compensated. And human behavior will tend to lead many people (especially poor ones like me without credit cards) to try to avoid annual commitments and stick with free sources (e.g. CNN on YouTube with inescapable advertising).
Question: How does Richard Stengel propose to do away with paywalls for news, "—at least during the 2024 election"? Has a potentially workable mechanism been proposed?

Screenshot of the beginning of Stengel's article in The Atlantic, as displayed to me, fading into the very paywallness discussed in the article:


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You can read the article without a paywall by using 12ft. This is his suggestion.

Of course, publications need to cover their costs, and journalists need to be paid. Traditionally, publications had three lines of revenue: subscriptions, advertising, and newsstand sales. Newsstand sales have mostly disappeared. The internet should have been a virtual newsstand, but buying individual issues or articles is almost impossible. The failure to institute a frictionless mechanism for micropayments to purchase news was one of the greatest missteps in the early days of the web. Some publications would still be smart to try it.

But he also states that without paywalls, subscriptions go up,

During the pandemic, some publications found that suspending their paywall had an effect they had not anticipated: It increased subscriptions. The Seattle Times, the paper of record in a city that was an early epicenter of coronavirus, put all of its COVID-related content outside the paywall and then saw, according to its senior vice president of marketing, Kati Erwert, “a very significant increase in digital subscriptions”—two to three times its previous daily averages. The Philadelphia Inquirer put its COVID content outside its paywall in the spring of 2020 as a public service. And then, according to the paper’s director of special projects, Evan Benn, it saw a “higher than usual number of digital subscription sign-ups.”

And, if nothing else, here is a list of potential revenue streams from the article,

They can enlist foundations or other sponsors to underwrite their work. They can turn to readers who are willing to subscribe, renew their subscriptions, or make added donations to subsidize important coverage during a crucial election. And they can take advantage of the broader audience that unpaywalled stories can reach, using it to generate more advertising revenue—and even more civic-minded subscribers.


Thanks! I'd never heard of 12ft. Interesting.

Does he additionally mention any idea for in case all of the above is not sufficient to cover the costs? Maybe something like wealthy donors or the government pays for all subscriptions during a certain time or the publishing houses could be forced to give a certain category of articles away for free a certain time after they have been published (say a few days)?
